# Is there any way to prevent specific websites from showing on browser search on Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, safari, catalina, websites

On iOS I use Zero Willpower to prevent specific websites from showing on search as well as block access to them. But I could not have found any way to do it on my Mac. Now I use dnsmasq to block access to certain websites but those websites still show on the searches, which I end up in clicking sometimes.

Is there any way to make those websites not show on the search result? I’m looking for a solution on Safari or Chrome (Safari is better though), on Google search engine.

Comment: Please indicate which browser and which search engine you are interested in.  For example [this macrumors thread](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/block-certain-domains-from-appearing-in-safari-search-result.1954688/) describes blocking Google search results in Safari.  If you use Chrome/Edge/Firefox rather than Safari and/or a different search engine it would be different.

Comment: @lx07 It is safari or chrome. The search engine is google.